# Spring Batch Job stuck in Infinite Loop when returning object of class type

Tags: spring-batch

I have a custom ItemReader where I am calling stored procedure which return Oracle STRUCT object type and I have ItemProcessor which uses this Oracle STRUCT as Input and Output as Object of Class. This step gets stuck in infinite loop when I return Class object from ItemProcessor. It is not invoking ItemWriter.

I have tried to read the existing question related to the same topic but it didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: Try to post the code you have in the ItemProcessor.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Issue is resolved. My ItemProcessor was looping because I was reading it from a file stream which was not returning null.